# What type is T?

Tags: java, generics, types

I have two classes which I want to generalize:

```
public class General<T> {
   T content;
   setContent(T content) { ... };       
}
public class Specific {
   Foo text;
   setText(Foo text) { ... };
}
```

`T` can be three different types, all of them classes. `Foo` is one of those, `Pair` is another.
I want to introduce an abstract superclass to generalize access to the attributes:

```
public abstract class Superclass {
    abstract void setText(Foo text);
}
```

Both classes (`General` and `Specific`) extend this superclass. But now I have a problem implementing the setter of the class `General`:

```
public void setText(Foo text) {
    if (T is of type Foo) content = (T) text;
    if (T is of type Pair) ((Pair)content).setHead(text);
    ...
}
```

What do I have to write instead of `is of type`? Is there any such expression in Java which gets evaluated at compile time?

I can check what type of `content` is, but I guess this won't work if that is null. Also, I could replace `T` by something like `? extends Object`, but how would I create an instance of (formerly) `T` then?

I googled but I couldn't find a sufficient answer to this specific problem.

Comment: There's no expression that would get evaluated at compile time, because the generic code will be shared. Instead, you could do something like `class GeneralInteger extends General<Integer>` and override `setText` in that.

Comment: You literally cannot do what you're trying to do, and will have to find another approach.  Some other comments have suggested ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 different methods for these classes:

```
public abstract class Superclass {
    abstract void setText(Foo text);
    abstract void setText(Pair text);
}
```

Comment: When I use those classes, I usually don't know if I have a object of General or Specific. If I would introduce methods only one of those has, I would need ifs with `instanceof` in *every* place I use it. No option.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having an abstract class use the concept of interfaces(with parent reference) then u can decide dynamically....

Comment: So I have an Interface which is implemented by Foo, Pair and every other type I might use there. Certainly the 'right' solution, but in my case, I'd prefer a solution less invasive.